# How to Create Fire Light like Ligthing in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I am interested in creating a fire light kind of effect for a footage. We have a 2d animation composition, and want to add a fire lighting to the scene. Think of a wall when lighted with a campfire or a fireplace. That is what I am trying to accomplish.

Thinking about using particular kind of thing. But not sure if that's the correct way.

How can I? Open to every kind of suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add some randomization to applying a redish orange color to the scene, but really, without 3d depth information it isn't going to work all that well.  Lighting falls differently based on distance from the source and angle of incidence and you can't compute that information easily or accurately from a flat frame.